# pandas period_range of several months with only cycles of day light hours

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I want to generate a timeserie of nearly one year, so I could affoard this using:

```
idx = pd.period_range(min(timeseries_), max(timeseries_), freq='15Min')
```

But I want to exclude night hours, the purpose is to impute via regression or any other method, real missing values, which may occur in day hours, because night hours missings are irrelevant to my problem.

Using this new index, I resample my train data, as follows:

```
train.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(train.index)
train_full = train.reindex(idx.to_datetime(), fill_value=np.nan)
```

Finally, identifying missings, I could impute them, without dealing with night hours.

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: it is very clear, adding a little context, just open the opportunity for people saying it's a vague question, it happens many time

Comment: *But I want to exclude night hours* from the period range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I came up with a toy solution, not that efficient, but does the job:

model night hours:

```
idx_m = pd.period_range('2017-03-20 18:00:00', '2017-03-21 05:45:00', freq='15Min')
to_be_missed = [(elem.minute, elem.hour) for elem in idx_m]
```

Now, remove them:

```
to_keep = [elem.to_timestamp() for elem in idx if (elem.minute, elem.hour) not in to_be_missed]
```